# hive insert / append data from two oracle table in CDH3 Machine

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive, append, cloudera-cdh

I am loading data from Oracle Tables into HDFS then external Hive
table. And after adding addition column ("SOURCE") finally moving data
into Hive internal table.

Oracle table USA_Transaction => HDFS => External Hive table => Added
Column [intermediate table "temp"]=> Hive Internal table

loaded data [usa transactions] into hive  internal table:-

```
from temp INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ds_transaction PARTITION(source)

select tran_id,
acct_id ,
tran_date,
amount ,
description ,
branch_code ,
product,
tran_state ,
tran_city ,
tran_zip ,
spendby,source DISTRIBUTE BY source;
```

Above query working fine.

Now I performed same process for Canada Transaction table

When trying to load data into final Hive table with below query :-

```
from temp INSERT  TABLE ds_transaction PARTITION(source)

select tran_id,
acct_id ,
tran_date,
amount ,
description ,
branch_code ,
product,
tran_state ,
tran_city ,
tran_zip ,
spendby,source DISTRIBUTE BY source;
```

Getting error :- " mismatched input 'INTO' expecting OVERWRITE in insert clause"

Note: If used OVERWRITE in the 2nd query then existing data [of usa
transactions] will be lost.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your statement to have the 'INTO' included. This will append the data instead of overwriting it.

```
from temp INSERT INTO TABLE ds_transaction PARTITION(source)

select tran_id, acct_id , tran_date, amount , description , branch_code , product, tran_state , tran_city , tran_zip , spendby,source DISTRIBUTE BY source;
```